# OSX Yosemite suggesting updates, I don't want to upgrade, but need to upgrade iTunes

Tags: itunes, macos, upgrade, software-update

My oldish MacMini has a fresh install of Yosemite (OSX 10.10.5). I go to iTunes, check for updates, and request to download 12.8.1.

MacOS then sends my to app store updates, suggesting an update which includes macOS High Sierra (see screenshot).

Is there a way to install the new iTunes without installing all these updates?[image]

Comment: Did you ever 'purchase' El Capitan? If it's in your history, that might be a better place to 'hold station' if you don't want the Sierras. If so, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos otherwise you won't be able to access it.

Comment: No, I did not. But would this work?: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1885?locale=en_US

Comment: No - see the linked question above. It is almost impossible to [officially] get hold of an older macOS/OS X if you don't already have it/own it. A combo updater will not work to **upgrade** to El Cap, only to **update** a lower minor version of El Cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check out Apple Support

https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1977?locale=en_US

There is a link to a 10.10.5 compatible version of iTunes 12.8.2. You must click this link for the 10.10.5 compatible version.

https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/041-37721-20190206-950874F8-AAA0-4373-96E9-A995A9B354C7/iTunes12.8.1.dmg

The 'Read before you install iTunes' document that is within the DMG states that 10.10.5 is supported on this version of iTunes.

Comment: When I try to install it, it says "This software is not supported on your system"!?

Comment: Not to be picky, but the actual DL link is to 12.8.1 for 10.10.5 - that would tell me 12.8.2 won't run on Yosemite.

Comment: I downloaded the "10.10.5 users download iTunes 12.8.1 here" version, that's the one that gave the error

Comment: you need to download the iTunes that is found in the link "10.10.5 users download iTunes 12.8.1 here". I posted that link above in the answer. This version is supported by your MacOS within the included docs, so perhaps a call to Apple is needed

Comment: I had downloaded that one. However, it appears I needed to install the Security Update 2017-003 10.10.5 first - which was in the list of suggestions from the App Store. After I installed the Security Update the "10.10.5 users download iTunes 12.8.1 here" install then worked.